# Can ListItem stay highlighted after selected?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I would like to setup a master/detail view and have a `List` on the left, `Drawer` on the right.

How can I have the last selected `ListItem` stay highlighted?

I'm using material-ui@next.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use `MenuItem` instead of `ListItem`. As described [in the docs](https://material-ui-next.com/demos/menus/#listitem-composition):

> The `MenuItem` is a wrapper around `ListItem` with some additional styles.

One of those additional styles is the `selected` option, which you can set using the `selected` prop:

```
<MenuItem button selected>
  <ListItemIcon>
    <FolderIcon />
  </ListItemIcon>
  <ListItemText primary="Archives" />
</MenuItem>
```

Here's a rough proof of concept that uses `state` to track and update the most recently clicked item:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from 'material-ui/styles';
import List, { ListItemIcon, ListItemText } from 'material-ui/List';
import { MenuItem } from 'material-ui/Menu';
import InboxIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Inbox';
import DraftsIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Drafts';
import FolderIcon from 'material-ui-icons/Folder';

const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    width: '100%',
    maxWidth: 360,
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
  },
});

class SimpleList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { selected: null };
  }

  updateSelected(selectedIndex) {
    this.setState({ selected: selectedIndex });
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    const { selected } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <List>
          <MenuItem button onClick={() => this.updateSelected(0)} selected={selected === 0}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <InboxIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Inbox" />
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem button onClick={() => this.updateSelected(1)} selected={selected === 1}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <DraftsIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Drafts" />
          </MenuItem>
          <MenuItem button onClick={() => this.updateSelected(2)} selected={selected === 2}>
            <ListItemIcon>
              <FolderIcon />
            </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary="Archives" />
          </MenuItem>
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

SimpleList.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(SimpleList);
```

Answer (score 3):

In **MUI v5**, you can use [`ListItemButton`](https://mui.com/components/lists/#selected-listitem) and use the `selected` prop to highlight the current list item:

```
const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = React.useState(1);
const buttonProps = (value) => ({
  selected: selectedIndex === value,
  onClick: () => setSelectedIndex(value),
});
```

```
<List>
  <ListItemButton {...buttonProps(0)}>
    <Content1 />
  </ListItemButton>
  <ListItemButton {...buttonProps(1)}>
    <Content2 />
  </ListItemButton>
  <ListItemButton {...buttonProps(2)}>
    <Content3 />
  </ListItemButton>
</List>
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to leverage `window.location.pathname`

```
<ListItemButton
     selected={window.location.pathname==="/path/to/current/page"}
     component="a" href="/path/to/current/page>
</ListItemButton>
```

Answer (score -1):

whenever you use `links` with list Items you can leave the item selected here's an Example ... I'm Using Vuetify..
[image]

Comment: Your answer doesn't make sense. Material-UI is a react framework, it doesn't work in vue.

Comment: Vuetify is also Material Design UI brother

Comment: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/ here you can testify it

Comment: What I mean is that [Material-UI](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui) is the name of the framework in react, it has the same name with the Material-UI design which can be implemented in other frameworks like angular/vuejs/flutter.. Have a look at the `material-ui` tag info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/material-ui/info), the tag name is confusing but what it means is that `material-ui` is a tag for react questions only. There is a plan to change this tag to `mui` in the future but it doesn't happen yet.